# Italic small caps fonts in .fd files

Tags: fonts

I want to declare a custom font family and one of my `otf` files is called `BemboTitlingMTStd-Italic.otf`. I want to use this whenever I use the command `\textit{\textsc{...}}` in my document, but I can't find anything in the `fntguide` on how to combine small caps and italic `otf` files:

> The most common values for the font series are:
>
> **m** Medium
>
> **b** Bold
>
> **bx** Bold extended
>
> **sb** Semi-bold
>
> **c** Condensed
>
> The most common values for the font shape are:
>
> **n** Normal (that is `upright' or`roman')
>
> **it** Italic
>
> **sl** Slanted (or `oblique')
>
> **sc** Caps and small caps

So do I really have to choose between italic shape or small caps shape, or can I combine the two in my `.fd` file?

Ideally the command would look a little like:

```
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Bembo}{m}{sc}{it}{
   <-> T1--Bembo--TitlingMTStd--Italic
}{}%
```

...But obviously that didn't get me anywhere.

Any suggestions?

PS: Feel free to edit tags or add tags, I couldn't find an appropriate one for the problem. Sorry.

Comment: Since you have `otf` files, is there any particular reason why you’re not using `fontspec` with `xetex` or `luatex`?  You’d save yourself days worth of work.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll consider it but obviously I'd still prefer the more general approach so that I *know* it will function as intended for documents that don't or can't use `XeTeX` or `LuaTeX` as well.

Comment: The package `fontaxes` might help.

Comment: But you need to use those to use an opentype font - neither `latex` nor `pdflatex` can use `otf` unconverted. If you had suitable fonts, you'd use `\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Bembo}{m}{si} ...` or `scsl` or whatever to define a new shape. But **you then need (1) suitable *TeX* fonts for use with (pdf)latex, (2) a support package to support the shape** e.g. `fontaxes` or `nfssext-cfr`. In either case, **your fonts must be named in ways those files expect**. (The packages use different naming schemes.) There is absolutely no *simple general* way for (pdf)latex. For this font only, Bernard's answer.

Comment: @cfr I can't find any documentation on when a `TeX` font would be "suitable" as you name it. Where can I see if my files meet the criteria for this?

Comment: The fonts need to have been packaged for TeX. In particular, you need at least TeX Metrics (`tfm` files) and map file fragments (`map` files or suitable definitions elsewhere). The map lines connect the real font files to the fonts-as-TeX-sees-them. What goes in the `fd` files is not the name of a font file in the sense of an `otf` or whatever, it is the name of a TeX font i.e. `tfm`. It is the map file lines which connect this to the `pfb`, `mf` or (for pdftex) `ttf` font which contains the glyphs. You can have several `tfm` files which use glyphs from a single `pfb`, for example. Or you...

Comment: can have a `tfm` which uses glyphs from several `pfb`s. To do the latter, you also need virtual fonts (`vf` files). The `tfm` (& possibly `vf`) which TeX uses as the font based on the `fd` file depends on the output font encoding (e.g. `OT1` or `T1`). These typically refer not to the font itself directly but to further `tfm` files which use the encoding of the original font or an intermediate encoding. For example TeX's use of ligatures depends on these files being configured correctly. (Ligatures includes e.g. `---` as well as `fi`.) Also, glyph sizes, interword space, italic slant, kerns...

Comment: @cfr What does `otftotfm` do then ? I used it to convert my `otf` files for use in `TeX`. I thought that would pretty much mean they are at that very moment "packaged" appropriately, minus ligatures if the font does not support them. I'm using my font map as Stephan Lehmke explained in his post with the declaration of `\usefontmap{Bembo.map}` and by using `fontenc`, `microtype`, etc. I pretty much followed the instructions to a T and it does seem to function as intended. I'm a bit confused where the problem is in relation to the use of multiple subsequent shapes?? `:-)`

Comment: Yes, that effectively automates the process I outlined and packages the fonts. Actually, you can control the process but it has an automatised option which is popular. It works very well but it cannot serve every need or font. We cannot tell if you have the fonts required - or how to access them if you do - without the details of how you used `otftotfm` and what you produced. However, do look at `fontaxes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer only: the `slantsc` package allows to `add` the `\scshape` information to other shapes. You can take a look at the `fbb` package documentation. It is an extension of `Cardo` (a Bembo clone) that has small caps in italic shape and bold weight.